# upload index error

Tags: php, upload

i have this code,

```
<?php 
include('menu/menu.html');
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<div id="search">
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table><tr><td><input type="file" name="filename"/></td>
<td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Descargar"></td></tr>      </table>
</form>
</div>
<div id="result">
<div id="nresult">
<?php
if ($_FILES['filename']['type'] != "application/pdf")
  {
  echo "Error " . $_FILES['filename'] . ": el archivo no es pdf.<br>";
  }
else
  {
```

And im having this error,

Notice: Undefined index: filename in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPEx\capsordenadores\Main.menu\upload.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: filename in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPEx\capsordenadores\Main.menu\upload.php on line 29

i dont understand why i have this error when i have defined the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined anything. You're rendering a form, and then attempting to access the data that form might *eventually* upload on a subsequent request. The `filename` index isn't created or available in any way until the user hits the submit button on that form.

Typically you would place the form-handling logic on the top, where it could execute and conditionally render the form unless the data is being posted back.

Comment: i have defined the index name,  and after submit e get the error

Comment: the "if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){" is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the code you are posting is not correct.

Initially when you want to upload a file , there were two logics :

1- Use same php file for displaying the form and for processing the upload :

Put the form layout that will contains the file field in a block , and the upload process in another block.

I mean that you must split your code into 2 parts :

- the first part will be executed if the page is accessed for the first time , and in this case the page must display the form that will ask user about the file you want to upload
- The second part it will be executed if the page is accessed due a post back (The user access this page after pressing a submit button within a form that point to this page)

and the code of the file [upload.php] must be look like this :

```
<?php 
include('menu/menu.html');
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    ?>
    <div id="search">
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="file" name="filename"/></td>
                    <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Descargar"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
else
    {
        ?>
        <div id="result">
        <div id="nresult">
        <?php
        if ($_FILES['filename']['type'] != "application/pdf")
            {echo "Error " . $_FILES['filename'] . ": el archivo no es pdf.<br>";}
        else
            {\\Procces your upload}
    }
```

2- The second logic is to put the form layout in a file and the upload process in another file and point the form in the first page to the second page look like this :

Put in the file named [uploadlayout.php]

```
<div id="search">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="uploadcode.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="filename"/></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Descargar"></td>      
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

And in the file named [uploadecode.php]

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['filename']['type'] != "application/pdf")
    {echo "Error " . $_FILES['filename'] . ": el archivo no es pdf.";}
else
    {//Proccess your upload}
```

?>

Now each time you access the page "uploadlayout.php" and you browse to a file then press the Submit button "Descragar" you will post the file choosen , to the "uploadcode.php" page and the test of the file type will be executed and if it succeed the upload process will be executed and if fail you will show the error "el archivo no es pdf"

I hope that i have explained that clearly and if you have another question or just you need any clarification just let me know :)

Comment: Understanding the logic of the process will help you understanding that :

because you are using the same file for displaying the form and for processing the upload , you must know when to display the form and when to procced the upload

And that's it when you test using isset($_POST['submit'])

you mean if the form is not posted so the page is accessed for first time and doesnt have any $_POST variable and the form will be displayed 

else the form will carry out variables $_POST['submit'] and $_FILES['filename'] and in this case you will procced the upload

Any clarification needed i am here

Comment: You don't reply if the problem has been solved or not yet if their were any additional help don't be late to tell  me :)